# Recipes to calm down my kimchi

Tags: kimchi

Last year,  I made some kimchi that tournes out a tad bit too spicy and sour. My partner refuses to eat it and I cry when I try. But there is nothing wrong with it otherwise. Om reluctant to throw it out since I have another full glass jar of it, but I'm not sure what recipes I can make with it which would calm the taste. The only thing I've made with it that really succeeded was kimchi pancakes. The flour seemed to mellow out the taste. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't share no recipes in here. Against rules!

Comment: No recipes needed, just ideas for meals. Is that OK?

Comment: Yeah sure, why not. You're most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sweetness to cut down on the sourness and spiciness. Use ingredients such as carrots, onions, tomatoes etc. along with kimchi to mellow it down. Or else you can blend a little portion of kimchi while making biryani(rice).